# Pulling data from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I hope someone can help me because I have tried many suggestions from other sites, but can not find the solution.

I have 2 workbooks. One contains the list of fields to be copied to the other. So far looks very easy, but when I try to assign the sheet name to variable, it does not store it so I am not able to return that sheet later.

I will give you an example

```
Function getActiveWBName()
    getActiveWBName = ActiveWorkbook.NAME
End Function

Dim homeWB

Sub pull_data()
    Set homeWB = Workbooks(getActiveWBName)
    homeWB.Activate
    Call Update_List
End Sub

Sub Update_List()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FullFilePath, UpdateLinks:=3

    Sheets("List").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    homeWB.Activate
    Sheets("List").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Paste
End Sub
```

After getting to `homeWB.activate` in the `sub Update_List` it returns `runtime error 424 - Object required.`

What am I doing wrong?

I would like to retain the function that returns active sheet name.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to go down that road :) I am not sure which site you referred to but you should avoid the use of `.Select` and `.Activate`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179)

Your code can be re-written as (Change as applicable)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wbInput As Workbook, wbOutput As Workbook
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet

    '~~> From where you want to copy
    Set wbInput = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> This is the sheet which has the fields you want to copy
    Set wsInput = wbInput.Sheets("List")

    '~~> Destination workbook
    Set wbOutput = Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsx")
    '~~> Destination sheet
    Set wsOutput = wbOutput.Sheets("List")

    '~~> Copy the relevant range
    wsInput.Range("A1:A10").Copy wsOutput.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an Object Required error because `homeWB` is not declared as a public variable, nor is it passed in to the `Update_List` subroutine.

You can fix that by passing the variable `homeWB` to the `Update_List` subroutine:

```
Sub pull_data()
Set homeWB = Workbooks(getActiveWBName)
homeWB.Activate
Call Update_List(homeWB)

End Sub

Sub Update_List(homeWB as Workbook)
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FullFilePath, UpdateLinks:=3

Sheets("List").Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

homeWB.Activate
Sheets("List").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Paste
End Sub
```

However, I would heed Siddhart Rout's advice above, regarding the use of `Activate` and `Select` which should be avoided 99% of the time.

Comment: Is homeWB required to be public ?

Comment: If you pass the variable explicitly as a required argument for the `Update_List` function, no.  If you would prefer not to pass the variable value between the subroutines, then yes, you would have to declare as public variable.

Comment: I made a revision to the way the `Update_List` sub is called. There is no error when passing an object variable between subroutines like `Call Update_List(homeWB)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
Dim homeWB As Workbook
Const FullFilePath = "C:\Users\Santosh\Desktop\ssss.xlsx" ' specify your path here

Sub pull_data()
    Set homeWB = ThisWorkbook
    Call Update_List
End Sub

Sub Update_List()

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FullFilePath, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)
    wkb.Sheets("List").Cells.Copy homeWB.Sheets("List").Range("A1")

    wkb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Santosh. This is the 2nd time you have posted an answer which is similar to mine :)

Comment: I m sure this post also would be deleted then. Good luck to me

Comment: No one is deleting this post :) Just wanted to tell you it's no point posting the same answer (or a variation of it) again ;)